# Letter Frequency in an array in VB

Tags: arrays, visual-studio, loops, frequency

I need help trying to figure out how to loop through an array filled by a text file not using LINQ and find and display the frequency of the Letters.

This is the Pseudocode I was given:

```
Read the words.txt file into a string array 

Declare an array of integers to hold 26 elements, call it alphabet 

Loop through the string array 

Loop through each letter in the an element of the string array  

 If the letter is not equal to “ “ then  

 Set variable ascLetter = ASC(Letter) – 65 

Add 1 to the element in alphabet(ascLetter) 

   End if 

 End loop  
End loop  

Print out each element in the alphabet array in the form of the
letter followed by hyphen then quantity
```

This is what I have so far:

```
   Dim alphabet(25) As Integer

   Private Sub btnLetter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)Handles btnLetter.Click

    Dim words() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("E:\words.txt")

    For i = 0 To words.Count - 1
        'Loop through the letters of the file 
        For position As Integer = 0 To words(i).Length - 1
            letter = words(i)
            ascletter = (Asc(letter) - 65)
            alphabet(ascletter) += 1
            If letter <> " " Then
                lstLetters.Items.Add(Chr(position + 65) & " " & alphabet(ascletter))
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: @RadLexus  
It gives me an error saying that the index is outside the bounds of the array

Comment: You need to start over and read the pseudocode again. Start with `declare an array of integers` (which you never allocated anywhere in your code). Then consider: if you have an array of integers, from 1 - 26 in length (one for each upper case letter), how can you *possibly* access an element at `Chr(position + 65)`?

Comment: @KenWhite the array of integers is alphabet. and the purpose of the the + 65 is to make it so A is the first letter show, when using Chr A = 65

Comment: You're right; I missed the array declaration because it was outside the proper scope (which is inside the buttonLetter_click method). Your math is still wrong. You only have valid indexes of 1-26 into the array; you can't **add 65**. Read the pseudocode again, as I suggested before, and you'll see the proper calculation for the index, and you'll stop having the index out of bounds error.

Comment: @KenWhite alphabet is a form level array which is why it is not in the button click method. The error i am getting though has nothing to do with the Chr function. It has to do with the Asc function. Even if i get rid of the 65 in the chr I get the same error.

Comment: @KenWhite I have a feeling that it has something to do with what i am setting letter equal too which is what is messing me up.

Comment: Use the debugger and step through the code. It will show you exactly where the problem is and you can see what's causing it, instead of just having *a feeling* of where it might be.

Comment: @KenWhite that is what i did. And i was right it is the asc function not the chr function

Comment: I ended up figuring this out a long time ago

Comment: Thanks Chris, very cool.